# How to link the csproj file with aml file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sandcastle

I am writing a document for my one application using Sand castle.
It consists of one csproj file in the document source.
I want to link that csproj file with my aml file page.
Does anybody know how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean simply adding the .aml file to the shfb project? That's as simple as right clicking the project and choosing "Add --> Existing..." and selecting the file.